# Explanation needed about the & operator in PHP?

Tags: php

i'm new here and i have a question that i couldn't find an answer to:

```
<?php 
$val1 = 25; 
$val2 = 15; 
echo ($value & $value1); // output : 9
?>
```

Can anyone explain step by step how this returned 9 ?

Thank you

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Answer (score 2):

`&` is an AND operator. It's sort of like `&&`, but applies to binary numbers.

25 = 0001**1**00**1**

15 = 0000**1**11**1**

.....& 00001001 which in binary is 9

Basically, only the bits that are 1 in both the first and second number remain 1, the rest turn to 0.

Answer (score 1):

`&` operator works with binary representation of a number:

`25` is `00011001`
`15` is `00001111`

```
00011001
       &
00001111
--------
00001001
```

Which is `9` in decimal.